# How to calculate the area between $y=e^{-x}$, $y=x$ and $x=0$

Tags: definite-integrals, area

My problem is that little point that comes from the equation $$e^{-x} = x$$
I can't solve that one. Is there another way without knowing that point or a way to calculate it?

Thanks in advance!

[image]

Comment: Unfortunately the upper bound is that red point there. But I cannot calculate it by the equation $e^{-x} = x$

Comment: My professor gave me that problem..

Comment: This is a numerical problem, I suppose, right?

Answer (score 3):

We want to figure out when $e^{-x} = x$. Multiplying by $e^x$ gives
$$
xe^x = 1
$$
The solution to this equation is defined as the [$\Omega$-constant](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Omega_constant), and shares many interesting properties. So we have $\Omega e^\Omega=1$ or $e^{\Omega} = 1/\Omega$ or $\Omega=e^{-\Omega}$. Several fast approximations can be found at the link above. The integral is then

\begin{align*}
A 
= \int_0^\Omega x\,\mathrm{d}x + \int_\Omega^\infty e^{-x}\,\mathrm{d}x
= e^{-\Omega} + \frac{1}{2}\Omega^2 = \Omega\left( 1+\frac{\Omega}{2}\right)\tag{1}
\end{align*}

Where we used that $e^{-\Omega}=\Omega$. For simplicity let us assume that $\Omega \approx \frac{5}{6}\log 2$ then

$$
A \approx \frac{25}{72}(\log 2)^2+\frac{1}{2}2^{1/6}
$$

If we really want to be fancy we can now use that $\log 2 \approx \frac 7{10}$ and $\frac{1}{2}2^{1/6}\approx \frac{1}{2}\left(1+1\cdot\frac{1}{6} \right)$. Where the last approximation comes from $(1+x)^{a} \approx 1 + ax$ where $|x|\leq 1$ and $a<1$. I will leave the rest to you

EDIT: The [continued fraction](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Continued_fraction) expansion of [$\Omega$](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mathematical_constants_by_continued_fraction_representation) is given as

$$[0; 1, 1, 3, 4, 2, 10, 4, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 7, 306, 1, 5, 1, 2, 1, 5,\ldots]$$

Hence

$$
\Omega = \frac{1}{1 + \cfrac{1}{1 + \cfrac{1}{3+\cfrac{1}{4+\cfrac{1}{1+\frac{1}{\cdots}}}}}} \approx 38/67
$$

Inserting this into $(1)$ and using $e^{-\Omega}\approx 1/\Omega$ we have

$$
    A \approx \exp\left(-\frac{38}{67}\right) + \frac{1}{2}\left(\frac{38}{67}\right)^2 
$$

Which is correct to about $10$ digits. Now $e^{-\Omega}=\Omega$ only holds for the exact Omega constant. Otherwise it is an *approximation*. Hence a tad worse version would have been

$$
    A \approx \frac{38}{67} + \frac{1}{2}\left(\frac{38}{67}\right)^2 = \frac{3268}{4489}
$$

Which is only correct for a handful digits ($3$).